# Default image will load for HttpPostedFileBase file object if it is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the following code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AdminDetailsViewModel viewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
         viewmodel.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
         HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData"];
         if (file.FileName=="")
         {
            // file object take image from this path ("~/images/computer.png");                                       
         }                    
         ImageRepository IR = new ImageRepository();
         int i = IR.UploadImageInDatabase(file, viewmodel);
         if (i == 1)
         {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }                
       }
      return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

Following is the view

```
 <div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminImage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" onchange="fileCheck(this);" />               
        </div>
 </div>
```

UploadImageInDatabase() function saves the image into the database

what should I write inside the if condition of Create function so that `HttpPostedFileBase` file object will take the file from  `("~/images/computer.png");` this path if it is null

Comment: you can store only file path in db and if posted file is null then set file path to **"~/images/computer.png"**

Comment: the code is saving image in database finely. In case if user don't upload any image, the HttpPostedFileBase file object will take the image from ("~/images/computer.png"); this path.

Comment: but you cannot explicitly add file in ``HttpPostedFileBase``

Comment: ok so what should I do to change if the file object comes null

Comment: So you want to show the default image when the user wasn't upload any image, is that right?

Comment: on diplaying check if image is null display default image

Comment: Yes Aravindan u r right a default image should be displayed

Comment: but it first it should be saved in database then it will display       I have used  this        `code <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.AdminImage)" width="100" height="100"/> `   in the  display and  edit Views  to display image

Answer (score 1):

Please use like below in your form on view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

Note : **You need to mention the enctype = "multipart/form-data" in your form this will helps you to get the solution.**

Comment: I have already done this in my View page the code is running fine but want that if user don't upload image a default image is loaded. Just want to change inside the IF condition of the create function